# Specify Retention Period for a HIVE Partitioned Table

Tags: hive

We are thinking in create a housekeeping  program to delete old partitions from HIVE tables. After reading the documentation, I found that you can establish a retention period using SET TBLPROPERTIES.

```
ALTER TABLE employees SET TBLPROPERTIES ('discover.partitions'='true');
ALTER TABLE employees SET TBLPROPERTIES ('partition.retention.period'='7d');
```

My questions are the following:

- After executing this command HIVE will delete old partitions ?  In
  other systems, normally setting properties don't affect to existing
  elements.
- When this clean-up takes place ? I did not see a way to configure it ? What happens if someone is accessing the partition in the moment the process is triggered ?
- Or it's just best to just create an script to read the metadata dictionary
  in HIVE and delete old partitions ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [link](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/using-hiveql/content/hive-set-partition-retention.html) metadata as well as actual data will be deleted

Comment: I read that link but it does not explain what happens with existing partitions. It says that it will delete older partitions than the limit reach after the setting is established. But what happens with the already existing partitions ?

Comment: existing partition will be available till the retention period expires

Comment: if at the moment to set the retention, I have a table with 30 partitions older than the limit, when they are deleted ? immediately ?  when the cleaning process is executed or how can I configure this ??

Comment: partition expiration starts UTC midnight for the partition's date

Comment: thank you @SHASHISHEKHARBarnwal . just last question. if the table has already 60 partitions from 60 days in the past, and now I set TBLPROPERTIES retention to 7, the other 53 partitions will be deleted automatically or I have to delete them by myself ??

Comment: its a day wise partition , ideally after setting this, it will get deleted for other 53 days, at least it works on BigQuery gcp.

Comment: and in cloudera ? if so, put the answer and I will accept it

Comment: @RobertoHernandez did you find it did in-fact apply deletion immediately?

Comment: @dlamblin , it does not delete old partitions if they were created before to apply the policy. My conclusion is that the policy only applies to partitions which are created afterwards.